# VirtualBox and missing packets in wireshark

Tags: linux, virtualbox, wireshark

I've been using virtualbox for some time for development purposes.

Under the latest version of virtualbox 4.04 where Linux is the host, I'm noticing that I cannot see packets sent to the virtual machine from the host at all in wireshark. I do however see the reply packet.

They seem to be missing from the output screen.
However, the Virtual Machine is receiving them. This is not the behaviour that used to occur.

Note that so far, I've noticed that UDP packets from my protocol and ICMP ping request packets are missing.  Is virtual box using a special network interface now that doesn't go through eth0 for sends.  I tried the special interface for all but again, it doesn't show up.

Does anyone know why I might not be seeing those packets? 
Is there a way to make them show through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hunting around seems to suggest that version 4 might be doing things a bit different than version 3.

This link suggests running wireshark within the guest.
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=31429

I have done that and can now see the sends and replies.